# House-Moving a synonym of Travel?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed the tag for [house-moving](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-moving) that only has a couple questions tagged with it. To me, I think those questions can just be tagged with [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) because that's what it's about, travelling with pets. The reason for travelling just happens to be moving.

Otherwise, should maybe just rename it to just [moving](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moving)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sold... I get where you're going, but there are considerations about moving that may be above and beyond the travel piece. For example, asking about preparations in new home for a cat, etc. would be based on [house-moving](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/house-moving) rather than just [travel](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel).

Comment: It seems like 'new home' would fall under [tag:housing] which is a synonym for [tag:containment].  It does not matter if the house is new or the pet is new, or something else has changed, housing is housing.

Comment: @JamesJenkins - Not sure I agree. When we moved our cats, they were definitely behaving very strange for the first month or so and that's specific to the act of moving.

Comment: Keeping in mind the whole broader tags trend that we are trying to foster (related posts not jumping out at me currently) do you think we need a separate tag for moving?

Comment: @JamesJenkins - I haven't looked at the current usage, but if it's all travel related then I would definitely agree with Matt.

Comment: Now I've looked at the current use... The first two usage seem to follow what I mention, but the most recent is really just a travel issue.

Comment: I would put those under the acclimation tag. Acclimation would be about getting used to a new house.

Comment: Yeah, that I could see working.

Comment: Should really be "relocation" not "house-moving".

Comment: I could see a relocation tag being helpful because it is different than just the place you keep them day to day.